# knockout JS: Unable to See Expected Results

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am trying to learn knockout by writing a small application. My code is very simple. I might be doing a small mistake, so I am not getting any results displayed.

Below is the code

**Index.cshtml**

```
    <div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach:list">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Content/MyScripts/PracticeScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**PracticeScript.js**

```
    $(function () {
    var data = [
    { name: "microsoft" },
    { name: "google" },
    { name: "facebook" },
    { name: "twitter" },
    { name: "Apple" }
    ];

    var viewModel = {
        item: ko.observable(""),
        list: ko.observableArray(data),
        addNewItem: function () {
           this.list.push(this.item());
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(this.viewModel);
});
```

Comment: use **ko.applyBindings(viewModel);** remove this

Comment: That worked! thanks a lot! tried modified everything except that 'this'..

Comment: it happenes most times

Comment: Agreed! what does 'this' point to in this case?

Comment: the document object..you can put breakpoint and check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you pass `this.viewModel`, but `viewModel` object does not belong to this..

so basicly you are passing `undefined` as your viewModel instead of the actual object.

***[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/A7upF4uZNBX73H85teZX?p=preview)***

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `this` from your `ko.applyBindings`

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jaq316/4hbJE/)